# Cannot filter assets for multiple densities using SDK build tools 21 or later

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

Due to an issue building my application in release mode with the gradle plugin 1.3.0, I have switched to 1.4.0 (beta 2), which fixes said build issue.

However, whereas some flavors build perfectly, others have their build aborted with the following error message:

> Cannot filter assets for multiple densities using SDK build tools 21 or later. Consider using apk splits instead.

I haven't found any reference to the sentence above, what should I do with the resources of these flavors, or even why this error only appears in a couple of flavors and not in all of them.

Edit: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.0.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix 'debug'
            versionNameSuffix '_debug'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "googleplay"
    productFlavors {
        noplay {
            dimension "googleplay"
            versionCode Integer.parseInt(defaultConfig.versionCode + "0")
            buildConfigField "boolean", "HAS_GOOGLE_PLAY", "false"

            resConfigs "ldpi", "mdpi"
            // so far we are using the noplay flavor only for old devices, which do not have hidpi
        }
        play {
            dimension "googleplay"
            versionCode Integer.parseInt(defaultConfig.versionCode + "1")
            buildConfigField "boolean", "HAS_GOOGLE_PLAY", "true"
            minSdkVersion 9
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Google Play services (analytics)
    playCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'

    // ActionBar and support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle (don't forget to remove signing options).

Comment: Done; thanks for your time.

Comment: Which variants fail? Is it always the same one(s)?

Comment: @stkent yes, always the same two: noplayLocnetwPaid and noplayLocnetwKids. The other three variants that I build (i.e. play*) are building fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

resConfigs is replaced by [APK splits](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits) for densities and architectures. Note the following [sentence](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking#TOC-Res-Configs):

> When using build tools older than 21 you could also add resConfigs
>   "nodpi", "hdpi" to also limit the density folders that are packaged.
>   Instead, use apk splits to provide different apks to devices with
>   different densities.

There is a [bug report for this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179136).

The offending resConfigs have to be removed, and apk splits can be used in their instead.

Alternatively, switching to build-tool 20.0.0 seems work around this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Further information on apk splits: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits and http://geeks.everything.me/2015/06/10/taking-the-ks-off-your-apks-part-1/

Comment: OMG - have been looking all over for evidence to that caused Splits to stop working all of a sudden! Amazing there is no warning or otherwise notice due to this...